# Requesting to one route but to me responding another route

Tags: node.js, express

I make a RestAPI for my diploma project and now I got a problem with one of my routes. I am sending a request with search params, but to me responding a route for finding by id. Maybe I just wrote incorrect request with params and my API thinks this is request with id?

My index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const adminRoute = require('./routes/admin');
const courierRoute = require('./routes/couriers');
const customerRoute = require('./routes/customer');
const brandRoute = require('./routes/brands');
const adminTokenRoute = require('./routes/adminTokens');
const courierTokenRoute = require('./routes/courierTokens');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

const app = express();
dotenv.config()

app.use(express.json({ limit: '30mb', extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '30mb', extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
/*app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}));*/
app.use(cors());

app.use(adminRoute);
app.use(courierRoute);
app.use(customerRoute);
app.use(brandRoute);
app.use(adminTokenRoute);
app.use(courierTokenRoute);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('App is running');
})

const CONNECTION_URL = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5001;

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, 
useCreateIndex: true, useFindAndModify: false })
  .then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Running on Port: 
  http://localhost:${PORT}`)))
  .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

My brands.js

```
const express = require('express');
const Brand = require('../models/catalog/brands');
const Admin = require('../models/users/admin');
const Manager = require('../models/users/manager');
const StoreKeeper = require('../models/users/storeKeeper');
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/brands/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    try {
        const item = await Brand.findById(id);

        res.json({ item });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).json({ error: 'Brand is not found!' });
    }
});

router.get('/brands/search', async (req, res) => {
    const { searchQuery } = req.query;

    try {
        const title = new RegExp(searchQuery, 'i');

        const items = await Brand.find({ name: title });

        res.json({ items });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).json({ error: 'Wrong request' });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I send request with id everything works well
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYomp.png)

But when I send request with query params I got error response from route where I search item by id
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkYrG.png)

What it can be? Thanks in advance for all the answers.

Comment: probably the order is important in this case. Try to put the router.get('/brands/search', ...) before than the router.get('/brands/:id', ...)

Comment: Yep, the problem was in order, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the Route `/brands/search` above the Route `/brands/:id` in './routes/brands/' file.

If you place Route `/brands/:id` before Route `/brands/search`, it will consider 'search' word as parameter 'id'